# Using jQuery to set HTML data attributes on a select option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, custom-data-attribute

How can I add HTML data attributes to a jQuery generated `<select>` `<option>`. I have the following code which programmatically sets the `<options>` of a select from the results of an Ajax query.

```js
$request.then(function (data) {
    var p_id = $("[name='property_id']").val() || -1;
    for (var d = 0, l = data.length; d < l; d++) {
       var item = data[d];
       var option = new Option(item.text, item.id, false, (item.id === p_id ? true : false));
       // this doesnt work
       option.data('data-owner_id') = item.owner_id;
       option.data('data-property_id') = item.property_id;
       $element.append(option);
    }
    $element.trigger('change');
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.data()` method takes the key and value paired. Try this:

```
   option.data('owner_id', item.owner_id);
   option.data('property_id', item.property_id);
```

Other than that, you can use `.attr()` method to add the attribute into your option. I will just give an example for you.

```
  option.attr('data-owner_id', item.owner_id);
  option.attr('data-property_id', item.property_id);
```

As the option variable is not a jQuery object, then you can't call the jQuery method like above function. The another option is using native JavaScript `.setAttribute()`.

```
option.setAttribute('data-owner_id', item.owner_id);
option.setAttribute('data-property_id', item.property_id);
```

Comment: Close... but not quite. I tried both and got Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function. I think I may have to add the attributes via jquery after appending them to the element.

Comment: At what line you got the error , `undefined is not a function` usually because you are attempting call jquery function that does't allow because the option already wrap as DOM. What about you change to `option.setAttribute("data-owner_id", item.owner_id)`